# How can I remove Sticky Keys Exploit via cmd?

Tags: windows, windows-8, registry

Recently, on my Windows 8.1 VM, I added a "Sticky Keys" exploit because I forgot my password. Now, I wish to remove it via cmd. This is what I imputed:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\sethc.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ /d "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

But it returns this:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG DELETE /?" for usage.
```

I am not too sure what am I doing wrong because when I used REG ADD, it worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must have a copy of `cmd` with name `sethc` in `Windows/system32/`. **Just delete that copy of cmd**.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but how should I do that?

Comment: OK. It must be in `C:` drive or where your system is installed. Have a look into that for `Windows` folder, then into that `System32` and then search for `cmd` and `sethc`. You will probably find two `cmd` there out of which one is copy of `sethc` (sticky keys .exe program) and you have to delete that.

Comment: For the time being disable `Sticky Keys` from All Control Panel Items and Ease of Access Center untill you get a solution for it. Also have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/732609/814740) and [this](http://kodu.ut.ee/~mroos/turve/2017/referaadid/referaat_OLahesoo.pdf). You will understand something.

Comment: I see. That would be great but I blocked explorer.exe as well (yup, dumb me)... Is there any to remove the registry key via cmd?

Comment: That's not a valid command. `\t` is for adding, not deleting. See https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is user confusion about CLI syntax and not appsec.

Comment: Don't delete operating system components. It is simply an error in the syntax of `reg delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

> reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\sethc.exe" /v Debugger

This will delete the value. You can do the same for "explorer.exe".